# SQL Query not including current month data

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query(value = "SELECT o.restaurant_id as restaurantId, YEAR(o.date_created) as year, MONTH(o.date_created) as month, "
             + " count(1) as tpn, sum(o.total) as tpv "
             + " FROM ordersDB.orders o "
             + " WHERE o.provider_id = :providerId "
             + " AND o.status != 2"
             + " AND o.restaurant_id = :restaurantId "
             + " AND o.date_created BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateUntil "
             + " GROUP BY 1,2,3 ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<IReportOrderEvolutionDto> getRestaurantProviderEvolution(Long providerId, Long restaurantId, LocalDate dateFrom, LocalDate dateUntil);
```

The problem I've got is that It only returns data from past months, not the current one.

If I select from 05/2023 to 10/2023, it will only return data from orders up to 09/30/2023 23:59, despite having orders created in October.

I also tried something like this:

```
SELECT o.restaurant_id as restaurantId, YEAR(o.date_created) as year, MONTH(o.date_created) as month, 
            count(1) as tpn, sum(o.total) as tpv 
             FROM ordersDB.orders o 
             WHERE o.provider_id = 1
            AND o.status != 2
             AND o.restaurant_id = 4
             AND MONTH(o.date_created) BETWEEN MONTH(DATE('2023-05-01')) AND MONTH(DATE('2023-10-31')) 
             AND YEAR(o.date_created) BETWEEN YEAR(DATE('2023-05-01')) AND YEAR(DATE('2023-10-31'))
            GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

But it didn't work either.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you sure you have data?

Comment: If it displays data till end of Sep when you specify Oct, then specify Nov to get data till end of Oct.

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @nbk yes, I checked ordering them by date_created.

Comment: @SalmanA I tried, but still doesn't work.

Comment: i really can't reproduce your problem https://dbfiddle.uk/M3CfyOdE

Answer (score 2):

If your dates are always the first day of the month you want to include, then you'll want to compare your end value to the month following the end date, because that date exists at the boundary of your date range.

```
SELECT o.restaurant_id as restaurantId, YEAR(o.date_created) as year, 
MONTH(o.date_created) as month, count(1) as tpn, sum(o.total) as tpv
FROM ordersDB.orders o WHERE o.provider_id = :providerId
AND o.status != 2 AND o.restaurant_id = :restaurantId
AND o.date_created >= :dateFrom 
AND o.date_created < :dateUntil + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I've got is that It only returns data from past months, not the current one.

I see that problem with your query is that you use `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` functions to compare the dates to the beginning and end of the month, respectively. It means that any orders placed in the current month will be excluded, since they will have a month value > the current month and a year value > the current year.

I tried to fix the issue this way:

```
SELECT o.restaurant_id AS restaurantId,
       YEAR(o.date_created) AS year,
       MONTH(o.date_created) AS month,
       COUNT(1) AS tpn,
       SUM(o.total) AS tpv
FROM ordersDB.orders o
WHERE o.provider_id = :providerId
AND o.status != 2
AND o.restaurant_id = :restaurantId
AND YEAR(o.date_created) >= YEAR(DATE('2023-05-01'))
AND YEAR(o.date_created) <= YEAR(DATE('2023-10-31'))
AND MONTH(o.date_created) >= MONTH(DATE('2023-05-01'))
AND MONTH(o.date_created) <= MONTH(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE))
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Let me know if it works for you, please.